# Triggers para verificação de data

Tags: mysql, query, trigger

estou com uma dúvida!

Tenho uma tabela de contratos e queria atualizar o campo de `data_exclusao` para a data atual toda vez que o campo `data_inicio` completasse 5 anos a partir do seu valor, porém queria que isso fosse automático no Mysql, é possível através de triggers?
Sou iniciante em triggers e sei bem o básico...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/events-overview.html)

> As tarefas agendadas desse tipo também são às vezes conhecidas como " gatilhos temporais "

Um pequeno exemplo pode ser achado na [documentação](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/) deles:

```
CREATE EVENT [IF NOT EXIST]  event_name
ON SCHEDULE schedule
DO
event_body
```

Comment: Isso funcionará semelhante à um "crontab" só que para o BD, correto?

Comment: Sim, só que a linguagem é diferente `ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE`